# Time to heat/cool a room

Tags: thermodynamics, time, temperature

So, I have a basic, very basic, understanding of thermodynamics. I don't take it until next semester. I'm attempting to write a program which plots a temperature over time graph of a room being heated/cooled until a certain threshold is met, the users desired temperature, at which point the temperature will drop at the rooms natural rate of loss.

I am finding it very difficult to get equations together for this. So far this is what I have:

- Room volume
- Temperature inside/outside/desired
- Heater value in kW
- Surface areas of windows/floor/ceiling
- Air density

I would be immensely grateful for any help or guidance, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I understand it conceptually, for the most part. I just really need some equations to work with. All I know that they're going to exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a resistors in parallel problem.

You have a heat source inside the room and a constant temperature outside (if you assume that the outdoors is infinite and well connected to the walls.  Then you have a thermal resistance/area for the wall, ceiling and floor material. Using the total area you have an overall thermal resistance and a temperature difference.

While the heater is running you will have an equilibrium where the temperature difference depends on the thermal resistance of the walls and the outside temperature.

When the heater turns off you will have a certain amount of energy inside (based on the heat capacity of the air and the inner wall material) and a rate of cooling. The only tricky part is that the rate of cooling is proportional to the temperature difference - so if you haven't done calculus yet you might have to approximate a series of time points in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I never thought of it like that. Definitely made visualization easier. Thank you.

I'm familiar with derivatives and integration if that's what your suggesting?

Comment: Yes - it's the same exponential curve as a capacitor discharging, or radioactive decay. So of course the room never totally cools. In practice it's trickier because the majority of thermal mass is in the walls, so you would have to model temperature differences within the wall thickness

Comment: looking after what you said, I'm looking at something along these lines

T(t) = Ts+(Ti — Ts)^e-kt

Comment: Looks good, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_conduction

Comment: so I could model this by having half the curve being the net  rate of the room heating and the other half, hvac shut off, the rate of cooling (or heating if outside T greater)?